# The correct way to declare common vars in babel

Tags: org-mode, org-babel, literate-programming

I'm playing with the idea of "literate devops" with org-mode. To simplify scripts i've extracted common values into `:PROPERTIES:` drawer, which looks like this:

```
* Scripts
** Subscripts-A
*** Subscrtips-B
:PROPERTIES:
:header-args: :dir ./folder
:header-args: :results output
:header-args: :var NAME='Alex'
:END:

#+BEGIN_SRC zsh
pwd
echo "NAME:" $NAME
#+END_SRC
```

The snippet above produces the following output:

```
#+RESULTS:
: /Users/4lex1v/folder
: NAME:
```

So ':var' arguments are ignored, while `:dir` and `:results` are fine, am i doing something wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> If you want to add to the value of an existing property, append a ‘+’ to the property name.
>
> (info "(org) Property syntax")

That means your property drawer should be

```
:PROPERTIES:
:header-args: :dir ./folder
:header-args+: :results output
:header-args+: :var NAME='Alex'
:END:
```

Comment: Oh, i've tried this, but added `+` to `:var`, works now. Thanks

Comment: Is there anyway to make that automatic? i.e merge these properties without using `+`?

Comment: You could put them in one line if that's an option: `:header-args: :dir ./folder :results output`.